# Apache2 mod_proxy with gitlab on different server

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-proxy, gitlab

I am desperately trying to configure gitlabhq in multi tier set-up, I have one proxy server websrv01.kosare.perlur.cz where I run Apache2 with mod_proxy, and then I have multiple Web Applications running on different servers. I have one gitlab-backend.kosare.perlur.cz where I have gitlabhq installed and when I try to connect to 10.10.2.2:8080 (which is IP and port of my unicorn server running gitlab) it works fine, but when I try to use gitlab.kosare.perlur.cz which is a virtual host on a proxy server forwarding requests to gitlab-backend, it does not work, it gets stuck.

My configuration file on proxy server looks like this.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName gitlab.kosare.perlur.cz

    RewriteEngine On

    <Proxy balancer://unicornservers>
        BalancerMember http://10.10.2.2:8080
    </Proxy>

    # Redirect all non-static requests to thin
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ balancer://unicornservers%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA,L]

    ProxyPass / balancer://unicornservers/
    ProxyPassReverse / balancer://unicornservers/
    ProxyPreserveHost Off

    <Proxy balancer://unicornservers/>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    # Custom log file locations
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/gitlab.kosare.perlur.cz_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/gitlab.kosare.perlur.cz_access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Does anyone have a clue how to make this set-up work?

Comment: That config looks incomplete, looks like something ate your apache pseudo xml tags.

Comment: Hi, indeed, config was not HTMLized, but it is ok now. Thanks for reporting.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the answer, but I find using both `RewriteRule` and `ProxyPass` for the same urls suspicios. Try without the rewriterule. Also, you mention that connecting to the backend works. Did you try that on the proxy machine?